# material-ui dropzone file reject on validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the materual-ui dropzone to upload files. I'm trying to validate the file on drop or on add, and reject it if it is found to be invalid. i'm not able to find a way to reject the file.

I have written some code in this codesandbox (link below), and added an empty function `handleUpload` which is called `onDrop` of a file. I want to implement some logic here to reject the file. could anyone guide me here?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dropzone-forked-vf60b

Answer (score 2):

Since `material-ui-dropzone` uses `react-dropzone` underneath, you could pass a [custom validator](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#!/Custom%20validation) in the `dropzoneProps`. Unfortunately, the project seems to be abandoned, you'll need first to make a fork, upgrade `react-dropzone` to version 11 to use the custom validator, and make some extra changes to fix some details. I made a [fork](https://github.com/diedu89/material-ui-dropzone) with the necessary changes and a [repo](https://github.com/diedu89/material-ui-dropzone-test) to test it

You can then point to your repo in the package dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "material-ui-dropzone": "git+ssh://git@github.com:[your-user]/material-ui-dropzone.git#[your-branch]",
    ...
  },
```

and pass the validator when using the component

```
      <DropzoneArea
        dropzoneProps={{
          validator: (file) => {
            return {
              code: "i-wanted",
              message: `Because I wanted`
            };
          }
        }}
        acceptedFiles={["text/csv"]}
        showPreviews={true}
        showPreviewsInDropzone={false}
        showFileNames={true}
        keepLocal={true}
        useChipsForPreview
        previewText="Selected File"
        dropzoneText={"upload csv file"}
        onDrop={this.handleUpload}
        showAlerts={true}
      />
```

just don't use my fork directly since I can't guarantee I'll keep it